# problems printing a tabbed report in Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, printing

I'm hoping this isn't a bug in Access but my research so far shows me that tabbed forms and reports are somewhat troublesome --

I've got a big report to print with more than 500 lines, 6 text boxes on each line; since Access reports are limited to 22" length (2 8.5 X 11 pages), I figured tabbed is the way to go.

Because there are, all told, 56 text boxes to go on each tab, I first created the model for my report as a regular (not tabbed) report.  Once I had it all working correctly (and printing correctly), I copied it in its entire into a 5-tab report.

As I said, it prints just fine in the simple report BUT:

Print Preview on the tabbed report puts a blank page or a page with a single vertical line on the left margin (it actually looks like it might be part of the frame of the tabbed page) or a page with a single 1/2" horizontal line at the left end of the top margin (which looks like it might be the page break but it's still there after I delete all page breaks) between every page.  So that in print preview my 10 pages wind up as 20 pages, 10 of the blankish.

It's worse when I try to actually print as I get only 6 pages, 5 of them blank.

Am I doing something wrong or do tabbed reports simply not print in Access?  Or at least in Access 2010?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have never heard of a 'tabbed' report. Did you find an example in some resource? This question does not involve code, just design, and is not really suited to SO.

Comment: Maybe part of my problem is that there are no examples that I can find.  I initially was doing this with a form but, when I ran into these problems with it, went for a report.  Biggest problem now seems to be that you can't really control the size of each page no matter how small your fill and it insists on printing the outline of the page.  Not too sure where to go with this MSoft is less than helpful.

Comment: If this is a Tab control on report, that hardly makes sense as a Tab control is an interactive feature of forms. Only tab page with focus displays. Reports in PrintPreview are not interactive and certainly can't interact with report when sent directly to print - so how would you expect data on each tab page to output when sent to printer? Not really understanding "insists on printing the outline of page". Might want to post into a forum that allows attaching files and provide db for analysis. Would subreports be appropriate?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  As I've not found anything anywhere that can make this work, I've decided to give it up and instead cascade separate forms named "myform1," "myform2," etc.  The idea (I don't care whether its a form or a report only that I can get in all the data) is simply that I have too much data to squeeze readably into Access' 22" limit.  Separate tabs looked like a way to to that (and, yes, tabs do work in reports exactly and to the same extent as they do in forms), which is why subforms or subreports don't help since they still have to be squeezed into 22."  Again, my thanks

Comment: "tabs do work in reports exactly and to the same extent as they do in forms" - how can you say that? I tested a tab control on report opened in PrintPreview - the tabs don't even show, only the data of first tab page shows. The tabs are clickable in ReportView but that does not help with printing. And the 22" limit is not entirely valid for placement of multiple subreports - subreport container has a CanGrow property. Make container 0 height and CanGrow Yes then push them up against each other. See how many you can fit within 22"